# How to Prevent "MySql has gone away" when using TIdHTTPServer

Tags: mysql, delphi, indy

I have written a web server using Delphi and the Indy TIdHttpServer component.  I am managing a pool of TAdoConnection connections to a MySql database.  When a request comes in I query my pool for available database connections.  If one is not available then a new TAdoConnection is created and added to the pool.

Problems occur when a connection becomes "stale" (i.e. it has not been used in quite some time).  I think in this instance the query results in the "MySql has gone away" error.

Does anyone have a method for getting around this?  Or would I have manage it myself by one of the following:

1. Writing a thread that will periodically "refresh" all connections.
2. Keeping track of the last active query, and if too old pass up using the connection and instead free it.

Comment: Put a timestamp in your pool object when you connect to the db, throw away the pool object when it is getting to "old" (ie x minutes) and create a new connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- store a *'last used'* time stamp with every pooled connection, and if a connection is requested check if the connection is too old - in this case, create a new one
- add a `validateObject()` method which issues a no-op SQL query to detect if the connection is still healthy
- a background thread which cleans up the pool in regular intervals: removing idle connections allows to reduce the pool size back to a minimum after peak usage

For some suggestions, see this article about the Apache Commons Pool Framework: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071834/build-ci-sdlc/pool-resources-using-apache-s-commons-pool-framework.html

Comment: Figured as much....  I presume the threshold I need to compare against is the "Wait Timeout"??

Comment: @MSchenkel see my update... wait timeout might be the time when the mysql client gives up waiting for a server response. The linked article mentiones a configuration option, minEvictableIdleTimeMillis. I would keep this setting independent from the mysql wait timeout, to allow smaller or bigger values.